# What is the difference between FormHelper::label and FormTagHelper::label_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a form which is dealing with multiple models.  Some examples of how to do this use [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper::label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001891), and some use [ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper::label_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002017), and I don't really understand the difference.

In my particular case, both seem to result in the same output:

```
<% form_for :post, :url => { :action => 'create' } do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag 'post_type' %><br />
    <%= text_field :post, :post_type %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label :post, :parent_post_id %><br />
    <%= text_field :post, :parent_post_id %>
  </p>
  ...
```

Renders:

```
  <p>
    <label for="post_type">Post type</label><br />
    <input id="post_post_type" name="post[post_type]" size="30" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="post_parent_post_id">Parent post</label><br />
    <input id="post_parent_post_id" name="post[parent_post_id]" size="30" type="text" />
  </p>
```

The label helper would seem to be more useful, because presumably there are some extra things it can do because it knows the model and property it's labelling, but I can't find anything to back that up.  Is there a practical difference between the two?  When should I use one helper instead of the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails provides two types of form helpers: those that work specifically with model attributes and those that don't. The *_tag helpers are for creating form tags that don't rely on an Active Record object being assigned to the template.

Although there's no difference in the generated markup for a `label` element as you've shown, in your case you should use the `label` form helper to be consistent with your use of the other form helpers and because it automatically sets the `for` attribute to the correct ID of the associated text field element.

Answer (score 2):

Use `f.label` when you are inside a form object created with `form_for(...) do |f|` and want to refer to a model-attribute. If your app is i18n-ed, Rails will use the translation to display the attribute name.

Use `label_tag` when you are not in a form object. (Or you are in a form object but want to create a dummy label for a non-model attribute.)

All form inputs have these two variants, with and without the `_tag` suffix, like `select` and `select_tag`, etc