# In rails, what distinguishes label from label_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, label, helper

I'm noticing in my rails views, some views use (helpers?) named xxx and other places use ones named xxx_tag?

Can anyone outline the difference between the two and how I can know which to use in a given case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between FormHelper::label and FormTagHelper::label\_tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010784/what-is-the-difference-between-formhelperlabel-and-formtaghelperlabel-tag)

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704366/difference-between-rails-label-and-label-tag

Answer (score 2):

`label` (and equivalents) can be called on a form builder (the object yielded when calling `form_for`), and so can be aware of the model instance the form's focused on, will automatically link it via the `for` attribute to the appropriate input, and may use I18n translations.

`label_tag` (and equivalents) isn't tied to a form, and is used for generating the label HTML tag at a more basic level. It's not as smart, you have to give it all the attributes you want it to have, but sometimes that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `f.label` when you are inside a form object created with `form_for(...) do |f|` and want to refer to a model-attribute. If your app is i18n-ed, Rails will use the translation to display the attribute name.

Use `label_tag` when you are not in a form object. (Or you are in a form object but want to create a dummy label for a non-model attribute.)

All form inputs have these two variants, with and without the `_tag` suffix, like `select` and `select_tag`, etc