# Difference between rails label and label_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails both label and label_tag seem to work the same. Are there any internal differences on how they are rendered by rails ? And which one is a better to use ?

Comment: you find answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1011069/2573383

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f.label` when you are inside a form object created with `form_for(...) do |f|` and want to refer to a model-attribute. If your app is i18n-ed, Rails will use the translation to display the attribute name.

Use `label_tag` when you are not in a form object. (Or you are in a form object but want to create a *dummy* label for a non-model attribute.)

All form inputs have these two variants, with and without the `_tag` suffix, like `select` and `select_tag`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean just label and not f.label.
The difference I have seen between using only label and label_tag is that you cannot set custom labels while using only label i.e if you use

`label :name, "My Name:`

in the view, it will not render My Name but just Name.
But if you use

`label_tag :name, "My Name:"`

It will render My Name on the display.